# Brent crude vs. USD market value

Tags: economics, security, usd-us-dollar, commodities

correlation != causation, but Brent crude and the USD are completely on twinkie paths

[Brent Crude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhFhc.png)

[USD exchange rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DYaS.png)

Why is it that when the price of oil drops, not only do you have more money to spend because the gas tank is cheaper, but also your dollar gains spending power?

Why are these 2 paths so much in sync?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the two are particularly linked.  While Brick is right in that the price of oil is denominated in dollars, I don't think that's responsible for most of the movement here.

Oil has been weak for intrinsic reasons related to oil: supply/demand imbalance, largely.  (Oil also was way over-priced back when it was > $100 a barrel; a lot of that was due to worries about instability in the Middle East.)

The dollar has been strong for other, separate intrinsic reasons.  The American economy has had a stronger rebound than Europe or Asia; while we were hit hard in the 2008 recession, we rebounded pretty quickly from a whole-economy point of view (we still have a lot of weaknesses in terms of long-term unemployment, but that doesn't seem to be hurting our productivity much).

Pick another time period, and you won't necessarily see the same matching path (and I would even say that those paths don't match particularly well).  [Marketwatch](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/gold-and-oil-have-a-complicated-relationship-with-the-dollar-2015-03-23) covered this for example; other sites show similar things.  There is a weak correlation, but only in the short term, or for specific reasons.

Comment: I agree that in another time period, you might see a different relationship because things are complicated.  As for right now: http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-01-11/morgan-stanley-sees-20-a-barrel-oil-on-u-s-dollar-appreciation

Comment: @Joe I am aware of market trends that correlate yet have nothing to do with each other. I am aware of why/how crude fell so low, but the USD shot up at the exact same time, with the exact same momentum. Like 2 dogs having sex but get stuck together, there is no denying they are connected, but how???   o.0

Answer (score 0):

It's standard to price oil in US$.  That means that if the US$ gets stronger, the prices of oil drops even if its "intrinsic value" remains constant.  Same thing happens for other commodities, such as gold.  Think of the oil price in barrels/$.  If the denominator (value of the $) goes up, then the ratio tends to go down.

Comment: there is a deeper explanation deflation of securities being linked to USD buying power. I understand the connection to circulation and the economy benefits but, I don't get the link to actual buying power.

Comment: @doeJ If you want some more information, see, for example, http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-01-11/morgan-stanley-sees-20-a-barrel-oil-on-u-s-dollar-appreciation  The nature of your comment seems to indicate that you didn't understand the answer.

Comment: That's Oil only in that article. the story of how oil got here is very well known. exactly how that USD is so tightly connected to oil prices, is unclear.